Is the woman collaborating with Bastion in "X-Men '97" a known supervillain from the comics?
In X-Men '97 (Season 1, Episode 8: "Tolerance Is Extinction - Part 1"), there's a scene that reveals that Doctor Doom and Baron Zemo are collaborating with Bastion. They're all sharing their thoughts on Bastion's sinister plan.

There's another collaborator, a mysterious woman, who makes a request to Bastion regarding the plan's implementation.

Given that Doctor Doom and Baron Zemo are among Marvel’s most infamous supervillains, I can't help but wonder if this character is also a supervillain from the comics or perhaps a character from the X-Men '97 predecessor, X-Men: The Animated Series. Who is she?

Beau DeMayo (X-Men '97 showrunner) on Twitter  says:

She is a human government official from an unnamed UN nation

So, as of now, no, not a known supervillain, just a politician.
According to Comic Book Club and users discussing this topic on this Reddit post, the credits list her as "Chinese OZT Member" (she's voiced by Jubilee's VA, but I don't think that's meant to mean anything), but they speculate that it might be Madame Hydra.
